# Search 0 answers question, tag or tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search

I am wanting search like this

```
newest 0 answer questions with [git] or [markdown] tag
```

I tried

[stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git][or][markdown]answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[git][or][markdown]answers:0)

and it is coming up with no questions. I know there are 0 answer `git` questions, and 0 answer `markdown` questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update:* This is now supported with the following search query: [[git] or [markdown] answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bgit%5d%20or%20%5bmarkdown%5d%20answers%3a0&tab=newest)

---

*Original:* This isn't possible with search currently, but is readable via `/unanswered` and the "no answers" tab, like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/git%2bor%2bmarkdown?tab=noanswers

Comment: @StevenPenny http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/get%2bor%2bmarkdown?tab=newest

Comment: @StevenPenny - that's not strictly possible currently (no *upvoted* answers is), though we're looking at it as a case for the search revamp.

Comment: @ms4py that is very close, but as Nick said that is for **no upvoted answers**, not **no answers** as I am wanting.