# See all 'answered' questions for a particular tag

Tags: support, tags, search

In Stack Overflow I follow the tag of `xpages`. So the URL looks like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpages

But in the page I can see only tabs of info, newest, faq, votes, active and unanswered, but not *answered*. Is there a way by which I can see all the questions with tag of `xpages` which have been answered i.e. answer for that question has been selected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpages%5D+isaccepted%3Ayes

Comment: Remember though - Just because an question doesn't have an *accepted* answer, doesn't mean it doesn't have a correct answer for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`[xpages] hasaccepted:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpages%5D+hasaccepted%3Ayes) this will show you all **questions** which *has* accepted answer.

[`[xpages] isaccepted:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpages%5D%20isaccepted:yes) this will show you all **answers** which *is* accepted.

Also [`[xpages] is:answer score:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpages%5D%20is:answer%20score:1) this will show you all **answers** with at least one upvote. (As [JonW suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167690/see-all-answered-questions-for-a-particular-tag#comment-493424))

---

**UPDATE:** [We can search now with `OR` keyword](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134826/187824). So you can search like this:

[`[xpages] or [lotusscript] is:answer score:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpages%5D%20or%20%5Blotusscript%5D%20is:answer%20score:1)

Comment: Thanks hims056. Now lets say I [follow multiple tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/) like `xpages` or `lotusscript` then how would I get answered questions for both these tags. Or does this require another question?

Comment: @Naveen - AFAIK [we can't *search* with **or** withing tags.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpages%5D+or+%5Blotusscript%5D) But [we can *browse* questions with *or* withing tags.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpages+or+lotusscript) So IMO searching is not possible with *or*. But yes [we can search questions tagged multiple tags](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpages%5D+%5Blotusscript%5D+is%3Aanswer+score%3A1)

Comment: @Naveen - See the update :)

Answer (score 1):

In the search box you may enter this:

> [xpages] isaccepted:yes