# How to query newest resolved questions?

Tags: discussion

I know how to list newest questions in my interested tags. I would like to follow several questions when they got resolved. Though adding it as favorite and tracking is possible, I was just wondering if there is a way I can list "Recently resolved" questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search recently resolved question by following search keywords:

`[tag-name] hasaccepted:yes` and sort it by *newest*. (select *newest* tab.)

For e.g. [`[sql] hasaccepted:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bsql%5D%20hasaccepted:yes)

[We can also search with or tags now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134826/187824)

For e.g. [`[sql] or [mysql] hasaccepted:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsql%5d%20or%20%5bmysql%5d%20hasaccepted%3ayes)

Comment: It works. How to use this to OR two tags. For e.g., i want to see accepted answer that has any of the tag1 or tag2.

Comment: @Galaxy - See my edit.

Comment: Works great. Excellent...